# Get Properties of object within list

Tags: c#, list, reflection

I am doing some dynamic form work based on properties within an object(creating a datagridview to populate the object). Everything works great until I have a List<>, and I get a Capacity and Count property but not the proper properties of said object.

```
dynamic ObjectToPopulate;
PropertyInfo[] PopulatedObjectProperties = ObjectToPopulate.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: Consider retrieving the properties of an item in the list instead of the list itself.

Comment: @HansPassant That's my question. I don't know how to get a single instance of the property when it's a List in my object.

Comment: one of the overrides for `PropertyInfo.GetValue` takes an index.  I'd start by looking at that.

Comment: @SamAxe What if there's no values in the object yet? Most of these are empty lists that have just be initialized and require users to enter data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it's a generic type which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, then you can get the properties of `T`. Here's a method which does it and returns the type:

```
public static Type GetGenericTypeOfEnumerable(object o)
{
    Type firstGenericType = o.GetType().GetInterfaces()
        .Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        .Select(t => t.GetGenericArguments()[0])
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return firstGenericType;
}
```

For example:

```
dynamic ObjectToPopulate = new List<string> { "foo" };
PropertyInfo[] PopulatedObjectProperties;

Type genericType = GetGenericTypeOfEnumerable(ObjectToPopulate);
if (genericType != null)
{
    PopulatedObjectProperties = genericType.GetProperties();
}
else
{
    PopulatedObjectProperties = ObjectToPopulate.GetType().GetProperties();
}
```

Note that this will not return `T` if the type doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` which seems to be desired. So if you have a `class Test<T>` you will get `Test`'s properties not those of `T`.

Comment: @KnightsOfTheRoun , go for this one :)

Comment: This is working. Other issues later, but that's from sloppy coding on my part. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.You can try some thing like this

```
        dynamic ObjectToPopulate = new ExpandoObject(); 
        ObjectToPopulate.Capacity = "50";
        ObjectToPopulate.Count = "100";          

       IDictionary<string, object> propertyValues = (IDictionary<string, object>)ObjectToPopulate;
```

`propertyValues` will hold both `ProperyName` and `Value`

Then you can get lists for both `Key` and `Value`

```
       var lstKeys = propertyValues.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
       var lstValues = propertyValues.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Doing this will defeat the purpose of using GetProperties.

My objects are settings for an API call that convert to JSON. Those settings are all sorts of types, string, int, and complex sub objects.

I need the type, as well as the name, as well as values. From what I gather, this will lose type along the lines.

Comment: Then you should go with Answer below by @Tim Schmelter

Comment: Didn't see that when I replied. I'm looking at it now. Thanks for the alternative, I'll definitely look into it for future other use.